# How to read back data from a text file when the dictionary is formatted in a certain way? [Python]

Tags: python, dictionary

Hi this is my current text file format;

```
A:{'1': [6, 4, 3, 8, 5], '2': [2, 1, 5, 4, 4], '3': []}
B:{'1': [3, 6, 4, 3, 7], '2': [3, 2, 9, 2, 7], '3': []}
C:{'1': [5, 4, 3, 6, 1], '2': [], '3': []}
```

How would I call the key of the dictionary and make it print the data in a formatted manner, from the text file.

Comment: That data would be easier to handle if it were JSON...

Comment: post the expected output

Comment: How did this text file come to be? Why didn't you just use some established text serialization format? What *dictionary* are you talking about? There is no dictionary, unless you aren't talking about a text file.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the key. For example:
`A['1']` 
Which would give you 
`[6, 4, 3, 8, 5]`

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import ast
# Read the file contents into a variable
>>> file_content='''A:{'1': [6, 4, 3, 8, 5], '2': [2, 1, 5, 4, 4], '3': []}
B:{'1': [3, 6, 4, 3, 7], '2': [3, 2, 9, 2, 7], '3': []}
C:{'1': [5, 4, 3, 6, 1], '2': [], '3': []}'''
>>> result_dict = {}
>>> for line in file_content.split('\n'):
       key_index = line.index(':')
       result_dict[line[:key_index]] = ast.literal_eval(line[key_index+1:])


>>> result_dict
{'A': {'1': [6, 4, 3, 8, 5], '3': [], '2': [2, 1, 5, 4, 4]}, 'C': {'1': [5, 4, 3, 6, 1], '3': [], '2': []}, 'B': {'1': [3, 6, 4, 3, 7], '3': [], '2': [3, 2, 9, 2, 7]}}
>>> result_dict['A']
{'1': [6, 4, 3, 8, 5], '3': [], '2': [2, 1, 5, 4, 4]}
```